# How to Resize Drawing using Swing Java using input

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to get an input from a user and use this input to resize a circle in JFrame.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CircleResize extends JFrame {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    CircleResize frame = new CircleResize();
    frame.setTitle("Tutorial 9");
    frame.setSize(800, 400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public CircleResize() {
    add(new Drawing());
  }
  static class Drawing extends JPanel {
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter x: ");
      int a = input.nextInt();
      System.out.print("Enter y: ");
      int b = input.nextInt();
      g.drawOval(200, 50, a, b);
    }
  }
}
```

Not sure why but it keeps asking for input even thought it is not a loop. I don't understand why.
Example of current output:

```
Enter x: 50
Enter y: 50
Enter x: 50
Enter y: 50
Enter x: 50
Enter y: 50
```

Comment: You should not be prompting for input from `paintComponent`.  Take input elsewhere and then call `repaint`  to make use of the input (if it is required).  And don't subclass `JFrame` either.  Just use an instance of it and add the panel to that.

Comment: A painting method is for painting only. Don't use a Scanner in the paintComponent() method. If you want input from a user when using a GUI then use a JOptionPane. You display the option panes in the main method. Then you pass the values as parameters to your Drawing panel when you create an instance of the Drawing class. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for working examples that provide better class structure. Start with the working examples and make changes.

Comment: Hello, if i put the scanner in main for example, it gave me an error. so how can i use it for the value of width and height for the circle? sorry if its a basic question but i really don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overriding `paintComponent`, which gets called every time there is a change to the `Graphics`.  There you call for input and call `drawOval`.  That cause a change, and so the event dispatcher calls `paintComponent`.  That's your loop.

Put your input into `main`.  Declare `a` and `b` within the scope of both `paintComponent` and main.  Then call `repaint ()` or `revalidate ()`.  That will cause a call to paintComponent (), not directly or instantly, but soon enough.

Don't call things inside paintComponent that change the state of the things used when painting.

*on edit:*

Oh well, I started posting only some bits but it soon became most of it, so here is some working code I whipped up, not perfect professional standards, but I think it will help you.

```
public class SandBox {

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        CircleResize frame = new CircleResize ();
        frame.setTitle ("Tutorial 9");
        frame.setSize (800, 400);
        frame.setLocation (100, 100);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // frame.setLocationRelativeTo (null); // Center the frame
        frame.setVisible (true);
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print ("Enter a: ");
        frame.a = input.nextInt ();
        System.out.print ("Enter b: ");
        frame.b = input.nextInt ();
        frame.repaint ();
    }
}


class CircleResize extends JFrame {


    int a = 100;
    int b = 100;

    public CircleResize () {
        add (new Drawing ());
    }
    
    class Drawing extends JPanel {

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
            g.drawOval (200, 50, a, b);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: May i know how to declare it in both paint and main? i would appreciate it if you can show an example since i am not sure how to do that.

Comment: I'm reluctant to post code that is fully functional and solves the problem even though I made it to verify it.  The reason is that if you try some things yourself you'll learn them better than read-copy-paste. But I will put some code in the answer.

Comment: Yes, i fully understand and I truly appreciate the help. but no worries, i actually need to create buttons that will control the size but i didn't want to ask for the entire question. I will try to use what i learn now into making the complete code.

Comment: I ended up posting a working program for you.  See  how the variables a and b are in the class but manipulated from outside. There are ways to refactor this kind of code for specific requirements.  Good luck.

Comment: @Alan Do not subclass `JFrame`.  It is bad technique.  Use an instance and add the panel(s) to that.

Comment: Oh, that is good to know. Honestly, its what we learned in class but now i will not do that.

Comment: @WJS, it is good advice (thanks for posting it) but it actually goes "... unless the code extends functionality."  I don't want to give this too much time optimizing it for perfect pro or educational patterns (they sometimes conflict).  In a similar vein I would look at refactoring to make a setter for a and b, etc. if I took the time.

Comment: Hi again, so when i ran the code, it only asked for a and b once each which is great. however, the size of the circle did not change and stayed the same. do you know what might be the case?

Comment: i  tried using redraw, however, it created more circles without removing the existing one. so i have 3 circles on the screen.

Comment: I just edited it to add repaint () as you were posting.  Try that.

Comment: @Freshstudent, there so too many things wrong with this example to list them all here. Take the time to read the tutorial link provided earlier and learn how to do custom painting properly. If you start with bad habits you will always carry them forward.